# If the stagename is matched, donot update Primary_Contact field

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger UpdateCustomdefinedfield on Account(after update)
{
   if(Trigger.isUpdate)
   {
       Map<Id,Account> AccIds = new Map<Id,Account>();
       Map<Id,Opportunity> OppIds = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
       for(Account acc : trigger.new)
      {
          Account Oldacc = trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
         if(acc.Primary_Contact__c != Oldacc.Primary_Contact__c)
        {
              AccIds.put(acc.Id,acc);
       }
  }
     List<Opportunity> UpdateOpp = [Select Id,AccountId,Primary_Contact__c from Opportunity where AccountId in : AccIds.keySet() &&(StageName != Null &&(StageName = 'Closed Won' || StageName ='Closed Lost'))];
     List<OpportunityLineItem> UpdateOppProd = [Select Id,OpportunityId,Primary_Contact__c from OpportunityLineItem  where OpportunityId in : OppIds.keySet()];
      for(Opportunity opp1 : UpdateOpp)
       {
            Account acc = AccIds.get(opp1.AccountId);
            opp1.Primary_Contact__c = acc.Primary_Contact__c;
         }
           Update UpdateOpp;
       
       for(OpportunityLineItem OppProduct : UpdateOppProd)
       {
           Opportunity opp = OppIds.get(OppProduct.OpportunityId);
           OppProduct.Primary_Contact__c = opp.Primary_Contact__c;
       }
         Update UpdateOppProd;
       }
   }
```

While using this Code, Am getting an error.Please help me to overcome this error.Thanks in Advance.
Error Message :
Variable doesn't exist: StageName
Expression cannot be assigned

Comment: Use `AND` instead of `&&` in your SOQL string. Also `OR` instead of `||`.

Comment: Also tried those and getting an same error @HengkyIlawan. Please correct this error and send am strucked here only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commentator is right, you should replace where condition:

Instead of this:

```
where AccountId in : AccIds.keySet() &&(StageName != Null &&(StageName = 'Closed Won' || StageName ='Closed Lost'))
```

Try this:

```
WHERE AccountId IN :AccIds.keySet() AND StageName IN ('Closed Won', 'Closed Lost')
```

This also would save you not null condition, because it isn't listed in StageName set.

Comment: Thanks @Mariia Illaripnova. I changed my condition to your logic. It is saved and no error

Comment: Hi. This logic is worked but the custom field in Opportunity product is not updated when account field(Primary_Contact__c) is updated.Please help me to overcome this error

Comment: ```Opportunity opp = OppIds.get(OppProduct.OpportunityId); OppProduct.Primary_Contact__c = opp.Primary_Contact__c;``` Here is the problem, in OppIds Map there is no updated opps like in ```UpdateOpp``` list.

Comment: Thanks @Mariia Illarinovia. I had changed the condition statement u gave and its works comfortable for me. Thanks for ur help